# How to install variable explorer extension in jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-contrib-nbextensions

I am running jupyter notebook through Anaconda Navigator. 
I tried installing variable explorer extension,

Although I was successful in installing the extension but I am not able to install its java and css dependencies

```
! pip install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
```

This works , however this doesn't works

```
jupyter contrib nbextension install --user
```

Any help will be apreciated

Answer (score 1):

Can you give it a try by using command:

jupyter nbextension enable varInspector/main

It worked for me.